WinUI TemplateSelector for ContentControl does not work
when i run my app, instead of using the data template i just see the full class name of my viewmodel displayed in the control. the MyDataTemplateSelector  class in instantiated, but the SelectTemplateCore is never called. i also get no first-chance exceptions.
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Normal { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        return this.Normal;
    }
}


<Window
    x:Class="Adventure.WinUi.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Adventure.WinUi"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:adventure="using:Adventure"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="ThisPage">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SceneDefault" x:DataType="local:AdventureViewModel">
               <TextBlock>Blabla</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate >
            <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector" Normal="{StaticResource SceneDefault}" />    
        </StackPanel.Resources>    
        <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" />    
    </StackPanel>    
</Window>


The doc doesn't help much about this. So, try overriding the other one:
protected override DataTemplate? SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    return this.Normal;
}


Just in case somebody cares. My solution was to port the application (very small application with single xaml file) from WinUI to WPF. I was amazed that only a few changes had to be made to the code, xaml syntax is very similar. And it worked immediately.
I have the impression, WinUI is dead (Same true for MAUI?).
